# How to Transfer Tezos via API or node rpc?

Tags: node, transactions, tzscan, eztz-cli

hello i m trying to integrate tezos api in node js. i already try this integration " https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/wiki/Documentation " but it won't work for transfer tezos from one address to another. any one has any idea about transfer tezos via api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this tutorial can help?
http://www.ocamlpro.com/2018/11/15/an-introduction-to-tezos-rpcs-a-basic-wallet/

Comment: i have following https://medium.com/@bakenrolls/sending-multiple-transactions-in-one-batch-using-tezos-rpc-6cab3a21f254 but i got error when transfer the tezos error were "[{"kind":"branch","id":"proto.004-Pt24m4xi.implicit.empty_implicit_contract","implicit":"tz1f7eZUXb8SSLbQTYnvniFmYkog72gKHbeH"}]"

Comment: Is that the destination address?

Comment: It could be a missing revelation operation, if it the first time that address is used to sign an operation.

See http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/introduction/howtouse.html?highlight=reveal#transfers-and-receipts

Comment: look at this transaction i perfromed https://alphanet.tzscan.io/onn6RvJbvivN5Wk25YUUuWtL5ykvdvUPdDouUzr4vd64KigGAnA?block_hash=BMN6AakaH1hg9MvwDuqDDCXR9PsVhVBhaiQjrtPAhbCwm4iht6e

Comment: here i don't know why it was fail ??